AWS test image before add it to ECR
I'm working on AWS, i work on a new architecture.
I work with github pipeline to build a container of my current app code and send it to ECR.
After that, i create a EC2 into a ECS with this build image.
But, currently i have one question i want to test my docker image BEFORE send it to ECR to to avoid sending corrupted images as latest version use by my EC2.
Do you have somes solutions to help me ?
The only solution I found is to directly run the docker container in my github runner which carries out the pipeline and then carry out a test that I created beforehand
 build-and-push:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Login to Amazon ECR
        id: login-ecr
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v2

      - name: Build Docker image
        env:
          ECR_REGISTRY: ....
          ECR_REPOSITORY: ....
          IMAGE_TAG: ....
        run: |
          docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG .
      
      - name: Run Docker container and test 
        id: test-status-endpoint
        env:
          ECR_REGISTRY:  ....
          ECR_REPOSITORY: ....
          IMAGE_TAG:  ....
        run: |
          docker run -d -p 8000:8000 --name test_container $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
          
          sleep 5
          
          if curl -s http://localhost:8000/status | grep "expected_response"; then
            echo "Status endpoint is working as expected."
          else
            echo "Status endpoint test failed!"
            docker logs test_container
            docker stop test_container
            docker rm test_container
            exit 1
          fi
          
          # Arrêter le container après le test
          docker stop test_container
          docker rm test_container

      - name: Push Docker image to Amazon ECR
        if: ${{ steps.test-status-endpoint.outcome == 'success' }}
        env:
          ECR_REGISTRY:  ....
          ECR_REPOSITORY:  ....
          IMAGE_TAG: ....
        run: |
          docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG


Take a look at bridgecrew/checkov.
